# SOAP Client, Following an example

Tags: java, soap, saaj

I need to consume a SOAP Server named "Mouser" for my company. However I have a problem when I try to send a message.

The documentation of my request is :

```
POST /service/searchapi.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mouser.fr
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Header>
        <MouserHeader xmlns="http://api.mouser.com/service">
            <AccountInfo>
                <PartnerID>string</PartnerID>
            </AccountInfo>
        </MouserHeader>
    </soap12:Header>
   <soap12:Body>
        <SearchByPartNumber xmlns="http://api.mouser.com/service">
             <mouserPartNumber>string</mouserPartNumber>
        </SearchByPartNumber>
   </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Ok, now I will how you my Java Code with the message that I send :

```
String mpns = "BAV99";

SOAPConnection connection = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();

SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL).createMessage();

MimeHeaders mimeHeader = message.getMimeHeaders();
mimeHeader.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");

SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
        + "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n"
        + "  <soap12:Header>\n"
        + "    <MouserHeader xmlns=\"http://api.mouser.com/service\">\n"
        + "      <AccountInfo>\n"
        + "        <PartnerID>" + key + "</PartnerID>\n"
        + "      </AccountInfo>\n"
        + "    </MouserHeader>\n"
        + "  </soap12:Header>\n"
        + "  <soap12:Body>\n"
        + "    <SearchByPartNumber xmlns=\"http://api.mouser.com/service\">\n"
        + "      <mouserPartNumber>" + mpns + "</mouserPartNumber>\n"
        + "    </SearchByPartNumber>\n"
        + "  </soap12:Body>\n"
        + "</soap12:Envelope>";

StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));
soapPart.setContent(source);
message.saveChanges();

System.out.println("Send : ");
message.writeTo(System.out);
System.out.println();

java.net.URL endpoint = new URL(targetUrl);
SOAPMessage reply = connection.call(message, endpoint);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(message.getSOAPPart()), new StreamResult(sw));
connection.close();
System.out.println("Received : ");
System.out.println(sw.toString());
return sw.toString();
```

Instead of get a the response that I want from the server I get the same message that I sent **BUT with the new ATTRIBUTE : standalone = "no"** 
What's does it means ? Why this response ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Header>
        <MouserHeader xmlns="http://api.mouser.com/service">
            <AccountInfo>
                <PartnerID>key</PartnerID>
            </AccountInfo>
        </MouserHeader>
    </soap12:Header>
   <soap12:Body>
        <SearchByPartNumber xmlns="http://api.mouser.com/service">
             <mouserPartNumber>BAV99</mouserPartNumber>
        </SearchByPartNumber>
   </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Thanks for helping !

Comment: What does your WSDL file look like?  Could you post the relevant portions of the service WSDL to this question?  Have you considered using Apache CXF instead?

Comment: Try to send a request using SOAPUI and see what you get.

Comment: This is the link of the WSDL file : http://www.mouser.fr/service/searchapi.asmx?WSDL

Do you think that's it's a problem from SAAJ ? Apache CXF is an equivalent ?

Comment: I tried to hit SOAPUI using but I think a valid key is required. this is what I get "Server was unable to process request. ---> Invalid unique identifier"

Comment: Hi Garry,

I just tried one minute ago with SOAP-UI, and this it's works ! I can see the real response with that I want, but now I need it in my Java project.

U receive this response because you didn't have an Mouser account

Comment: I try with the same message than SOAP-UI and same target but I always get the same response from the server

Comment: Are you using the SAAJ implementation in the JRE or some other implementation? What is the result of `System.out.println(SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().getClass().getName())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do ! Thanks everybody, an particularly at **foolvoe99** because it's with your idea that's I knew where to search.

I used "wsimport" to generate java class from WSDL and used them.
Here is how I did it, so this can help others :

```
URL wsdlLocation = new URL("your_wsdl_target");
QName apiName = new QName("your_service_target", "your_service_name");
your_service_name api = new your_service_name(wsdlLocation, apiName);
api.addPort(your_service_name, SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING, "your_service_target/name");

QName port_name = new QName("your_service_target", "port_name");
Dispatch<SOAPMessage> disp = api.createDispatch(port_name, SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);            

String xml = "Your SOAP MESSAGE";

MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
SOAPMessage request = mf.createMessage();
SOAPPart part = request.getSOAPPart();
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));
part.setContent(source);
request.saveChanges();

SOAPMessage response = disp.invoke(request);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(response.getSOAPPart()), new StreamResult(sw));
org.json.JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(sw.toString());
return xmlJSONObj.toString(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can generate class with soap ui. And your program can easily call the service using the class created without construct your own request header and body
But you need some library. Example java jdk comes with jax-ws lib

tutorial: http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/soap-code-generation.html